# Unable to locate package mozilla-acroread

Tags: firefox

I just upgraded to 10.10 and installed Acrobat via Adobe's website. I can't seem to get the Firefox plugin. I updated my software sources to include mediabuntu, but when I enter  `sudo apt-get install mozilla-acroread` I get "Unable to locate package mozilla-acroread"

Comment: I use document viewer to read pdf, so I don't need acrobat reader plug-in.  It doesn't support in-line pdf reading, but it has worked for me.  Just how I handle the problem.

Comment: After having troubles going down the Acrobat route in regarding to in-line reading, I've chosen to use the Document Viewer (evince) method; however, I've discovered it is possible to do inline (see this: http://sprayfly.com/2010/01/15/view-pdf-files-inline-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-karmic-9-10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Medibuntu repository [doesn't contain](http://packages.medibuntu.org/maverick/index.html) the `mozilla-acroread` package - that's why 
your `apt-get install` can't find it. You came across this error because things [have changed in more recent Ubuntu versions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu#Note%20about%20Adobe%20Acrobat%20Reader%20(acroread)) so old instructions won't work.

The way forward is to install Adobe Reader from the Ubuntu Software Centre which should automatically install the Firefox plugin alongside it (you may need to restart Firefox).

If Adobe Reader doesn't appear in the Software Centre you need to make sure you have the Canonical Partner repositories enabled. You can do this by running `gksu gedit /apt/sources.list` in a terminal and checking that you have the following lines there (*without* a `#` in front of them).

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if you have the **Canonical Partner** repositories enabled. This can be done in the Software Center:

Go to Edit menu → Software Sources

Enter password

Click on '**Other Software**' tab

Make sure '**Canonical Partners**' box is checked.